# When closing as a duplicate, show New User's other posts in the list

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-answers, close-dialog

Sometimes, a new user will post a duplicate of an old question. When the duplicate close list is displayed, please could all the recent (3 week old) posts of a new user (less than 50 / 100 / another amount of rep) be displayed there too?

Comment: I like the idea, but what is a "new" user?

Comment: @James 50 / 100 rep? I think SE already have a "new user" id thingamy.

Answer (score 3):

Just showing *all* of a user's previous posts might be a waste of time, as then we have to rake through them to find a dupe, which is laborious and not many people will likely bother.

So instead, and slightly *advancing* your (great) idea, it might be good to use the site's dupe/related question identifier* to show any *similar* questions asked by the same user who's question we are closing as a dupe.

As this will return a lot less questions even for a non-new user, we don't need a rep limit, or it could be high (2k). As a user's rep doesn't necessarily reflect good behaviour, or knowledge as to what *really* constitutes a dupe, etc.

---

* = i.e. when you type a new question out it shows you related questions, same as the side bar "Related" (etc).